# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-login-twitter:compileDebugAidl'

Tags: javascript, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmEZr.png)

I want to use twitter for login/signup credentials and for this process this library react-native-twitter-signin and I followed  all the instructions related to it, but I get this problem on Android.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not an image.